# Windows 8 navigating with header menus and section labels in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

How can I make a navigation menu in Windows 8 with header menus and section labels like the picture below using XAML?

[image: header menus and section labels]

Picture taken from: [Navigation design for Metro style apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761500.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't possible...

**Currently (as of Release Preview) there is no out-of-the-box solution or SDK-provided control for creating the header menu in a Windows 8 Metro app. In this post I’ll demonstrate a quick and easy way to build one.** July 6, 2012.

and I can't find any way in RC either,

...but check out the best solution from Karl Ots with a full sample code for download [How to create a header menu navigation in a Windows 8 Metro-style app](http://fincooper.azurewebsites.net/2012/07/how-to-create-header-menu-windows/)

*Just have fun trying...*

---

**UPDATE**

Have a unfinished sample fully (I hope!) commented in the XAML & CS files for download at:
[NavAppWin8 (7-zip format)](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=11E37A277FE30BD1&id=11E37A277FE30BD1!113)
It's not the prettiest code I'm sure, just hope it helps a little.